# How to split an array into chunks based on curly braces(in jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I'm not able to split this array into two separate chunks.

```
[{"allowChildren":false,"allowDrag":false,"allowDrop":false,"cls":"resource-facility-group","disabled":false,"draggable":false,"editable":false,"expandable":false,"expanded":false,"hidden":false,"href":"","hrefTarget":"","icon":"","iconCls":"resource-facility-group","id":"RESFACCONT--1","leaf":false,"onSelectFunc":"javascript:clearViewPanel()","qtip":"","qtipCfg":"","shortName":"_facilities","singleClickExpand":true,"target":false,"text":"Facilities & Classrooms"},
 {"allowChildren":false,"allowDrag":false,"allowDrop":false,"cls":"resource-contact-group","disabled":false,"draggable":false,"editable":false,"expandable":false,"expanded":false,"hidden":false,"href":"","hrefTarget":"","icon":"","iconCls":"resource-contact-group","id":"RESCONCONT--1","leaf":false,"onSelectFunc":"javascript:clearViewPanel()","qtip":"","qtipCfg":"","shortName":"_contacts","singleClickExpand":true,"target":false,"text":"Contacts"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide the source code that doesn't work and let us know what part of it is cause the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips on asking good questions!

Comment: what do you want to split to ? you can always access elements of array like this `array[0]`, `array[2]`

Comment: I'm getting a result like this.......array[0] = "{", array[1] = '"', array[2]="a" and so on

Comment: what is your expected result and what are you getting. also how are you splitting it? please add it to the question (not as a comment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
var o = [{"allowChildren":false,"allowDrag":false,"allowDrop":false,"cls":"resource-facility-group","disabled":false,"draggable":false,"editable":false,"expandable":false,"expanded":false,"hidden":false,"href":"","hrefTarget":"","icon":"","iconCls":"resource-facility-group","id":"RESFACCONT--1","leaf":false,"onSelectFunc":"javascript:clearViewPanel()","qtip":"","qtipCfg":"","shortName":"_facilities","singleClickExpand":true,"target":false,"text":"Facilities & Classrooms"},{"allowChildren":false,"allowDrag":false,"allowDrop":false,"cls":"resource-contact-group","disabled":false,"draggable":false,"editable":false,"expandable":false,"expanded":false,"hidden":false,"href":"","hrefTarget":"","icon":"","iconCls":"resource-contact-group","id":"RESCONCONT--1","leaf":false,"onSelectFunc":"javascript:clearViewPanel()","qtip":"","qtipCfg":"","shortName":"_contacts","singleClickExpand":true,"target":false,"text":"Contacts"}];

var arr = $.map(o, function(el) { return el; })
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/8TT4p/1586/)

Comment: But I'm getting an error saying "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '971'............", as the array here, is not being considered as a JSON !!

Comment: @IndhumathyGopalakrishnan you can take a particular filed from array like arr[0].iconCls , Use " . "operator for that.

Comment: This problem is while trying to split the array:P

Comment: Can you post the code which you are trying as a comment?

Comment: From an ajax call, I'm getting this array data. I'm getting oly a single character, for o[i] and not the whole obj enclosed with "{}"

Comment: Now, the result is each character enclosed with "", that didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON`

Script:

```
var json='array string'
var obj=JSON.parse(json)
var map1=obj[0]
var map2=obj[1]
```

now you have `map1` and `map2` with the data inside the curly braces.

you can access the data as JSON like:

```
var val=map1.allowChildren//will return false
```

Or you can convert back into string by using:

```
var str=JSON.stringify(map1)
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
 You can use below loop to iterate the object.
*/

```
var js_obj = [{
    "allowChildren": false,
    "allowDrag": false,
    "allowDrop": false,
    "cls": "resource-facility-group",
    "disabled": false,
    "draggable": false,
    "editable": false,
    "expandable": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "href": "",
    "hrefTarget": "",
    "icon": "",
    "iconCls": "resource-facility-group",
    "id": "RESFACCONT--1",
    "leaf": false,
    "onSelectFunc": "javascript:clearViewPanel()",
    "qtip": "",
    "qtipCfg": "",
    "shortName": "_facilities",
    "singleClickExpand": true,
    "target": false,
    "text": "Facilities & Classrooms"
}, {
    "allowChildren": false,
    "allowDrag": false,
    "allowDrop": false,
    "cls": "resource-contact-group",
    "disabled": false,
    "draggable": false,
    "editable": false,
    "expandable": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "href": "",
    "hrefTarget": "",
    "icon": "",
    "iconCls": "resource-contact-group",
    "id": "RESCONCONT--1",
    "leaf": false,
    "onSelectFunc": "javascript:clearViewPanel()",
    "qtip": "",
    "qtipCfg": "",
    "shortName": "_contacts",
    "singleClickExpand": true,
    "target": false,
    "text": "Contacts"
}];
for(var i in js_obj){
    //alert(i);
  for(var j in js_obj[i]){
    console.log(js_obj[i][j]);
  }
}
```